# Listar dados de Json com Angular 2

Tags: json, angular, typescript

considerando que tenho um Json vindo de uma Url ('https://api.site.com.br/v1/servicos').
Criei uma service para pegar este objeto:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';

    @Injectable()
    export class PlanosService {
      //get Json Servicos
        planos: Object[] = [];
        constructor(http: Http) {
          http
          .get('https://api.carguruclub.com/v1/servicos')
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(planos => {
            this.planos = planos;
            console.log(this.planos);
          }, erro => console.log(erro));
        }
    }
```

Até aí tudo bem.
Porém, minha dúvida é em como listar os elementos deste objeto.. Por exemplo, queria pegar o {{products.name}} e exibir aquele trecho do json e no meu component.
Não entendi muito bem os caminhos que devo seguir, pois sou iniciante.
Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1):

Segue um plunker que criei como exemplo: https://plnkr.co/edit/uXAKd17lCOdxBzRG6CVs?p=preview

**Você precisa no componente inserir o serviço criado como um provider**

```
import {PlanosService} from 'src/planos.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'src/main.html',
  providers: [PlanosService]
})
```

**Após fazer isso, no constructor você referência o serviço.**

```
  constructor(public prdService: PlanosService) {

  }
```

Como você já está colocando a variável dentro do serviço no html você usa a referência criada no constructor acima como um *ngFor para fazer o loop

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Descrição</th>
      <th>Preço</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let plano of prdService.planos.products">
      <td>{{plano.name}}</td>
      <td>{{plano.desc}}</td>
      <td>{{plano.price}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Lembrando que para usar o map é necesssário importar o map operator do rxjs

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
```